# Attribute Randomize node is missing 'add'

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: help]
i am following a tutorial and the node is missing the add option.

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you're talking about the Default Cube tutorial. He's using the 2.93 alpha build and you're probably using 2.92. Anytime you're not getting the same options in a feature, it's probably because of a version mismatch. I did however find a workaround in 2.92; here's what worked for me after a little experimentation:

[image: Attribute Randomize Add workaround]

I imagine there's a better way to do this, but it's my first time using geometry nodes. I'd love to hear constructive criticism about this setup.